# Intelli Jetty runner plugin error

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, plugins, runtime-error

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/AsyncRequestTimeoutException

I have Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE. 
How specify other spring-web in plugin or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like an issue with the IntelliJ Jetty Runner plugin.

The issue is with your classpath:
`NoClassDefFoundError: AsyncRequestTimeoutException`

Your classpath is missing "spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar"; add it to your classpath.
As a suggestion, use a dependency manager like **Maven** or **Gradle** to make your life easier.

Best of luck!